ngageoint/geopackage-android Writing in GPKG from android
I have a project where i have to export coordinates data into a GPKG with media as blob from my app, so it can be opened in QGIS.
I have no experience at all in this field and have been battling for days to have something working.
My idea was to have an already constructed gpkg in my assets file, open it with ngageoint/geopackage-android (and ios) and fill the FeatureTable / FeatureRow / GeometryColumns.
So i have a GPKG ready with my 3 tables, and all the rest generated by QGIS.

I also have all the triggers:

On Android i insert my feature rows like this:
private fun manageExportTrackPointsGpkg(geoPackage: GeoPackage, appPoint: AppPoint) {
   val featureDao = geoPackage.getFeatureDao("track_points")

   val point = Point(appPoint.latitude, appPoint.longitude)

   val newRow = featureDao.newRow()
   newRow.geometry = GeoPackageGeometryData.createAndWrite(point)
   /// other values...
   newRow.setValue("timeStamp", ...)
        
   featureDao.insert(newRow)
}

This part works (i think).
But the table gpkg_contents is not updated. So i do it manually:
val trackPointsFeatureDao = geoPackage.getFeatureDao("track_points")
val trackPointsContent = trackPointsFeatureDao.contents
trackPointsContent.lastChange = Date()
trackPointsContent.minY = pointMinY
trackPointsContent.maxY = pointMaxY
trackPointsContent.minX = pointMinX
trackPointsContent.maxX = pointMaxX
val update = geoPackage.contentsDao.update(trackPointsContent)

The table is now updated.
But the spatials tables' triggers are not working and thus the spatials data are not filled.
CREATE TRIGGER "rtree_track_points_geom_insert" AFTER INSERT ON "track_points" WHEN (new."geom" NOT NULL AND NOT ST_IsEmpty(NEW."geom")) BEGIN INSERT OR REPLACE INTO "rtree_track_points_geom" VALUES (NEW."fid",ST_MinX(NEW."geom"), ST_MaxX(NEW."geom"),ST_MinY(NEW."geom"), ST_MaxY(NEW."geom")); END

Apparently the ST_IsEmpty does not exists ?
So when i load my gpkg on QGIS nothing is displayed.
I couldn't find any method to update the spatial tables, and the raw query is not working
(1) no such module: rtree in "INSERT INTO rtree_track_points_geom(minx, maxx, miny, maxy) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"

I was unable to find a clear documentation on how to write into a GPKG with the library.
What am i doing wrong ? How to easily write into a GPKG ?
Thanks in advance.

I finally found the page where the library's creator have plenty example on how to create and fill a GPKG:
https://github.com/ngageoint/geopackage-android/blob/134d0ddd1074f4de11b87ef8112530105f95f6ff/geopackage-sdk/src/androidTest/java/mil/nga/geopackage/test/GeoPackageExample.java
Much easier to follow and it works !

Your issue, the rtree module not found, appears to indicate that the TRIGGER is being triggered and the attempt is being made to insert or replace the row into the rtree_track_points_geom table BUT that the module rtree is not a registered module.
Virtual tables, which the rtree_track_points_geom is, are special tables that are "controlled" by a module.

From the perspective of an SQL statement, the virtual table object looks like any other table or view. But behind the scenes, queries and updates on a virtual table invoke callback methods of the virtual table object instead of reading and writing on the database file. as per https://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html

The rtree (R*Tree) module is an SQLite provided module BUT by default is disabled.

perhaps see https://sqlite.org/rtree.html


The makefiles for SQLite have an "sqlite3.c" target for building the amalgamation, to contain all C code for the core SQLite library and the FTS3, FTS5, RTREE, DBSTAT, JSON1, RBU and SESSION extensions. This file contains about 238K lines of code (or 145K if you omit blank lines and comments) and is over 8.4 megabytes in size (as of 2021-12-29).


Though the various extensions are included in the "sqlite3.c" amalgamation file, they are disabled using #ifdef statements. Activate the extensions using compile-time options like:



-DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS5
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_DBSTAT_VTAB
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_RBU
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_SESSION


Saying that FTS3 and FTS5 are typically enabled in Android distributions.
To fix the issue you need an SQLite distribution that includes an enabled RTree.
You may find this useful Android SQLite R-Tree - How to install module?

Thank you for you answer. I opted to find another solution without the module rtree.
